# How to manage dcu-cli GUI in powershell remote job

Tags: powershell, driver, powershell-remoting

I'm currently working on a script to update remote machine through Powershell, for that I'm using dcu-cli.exe.

It works fine if ran directly on Local Machine like :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe" /ApplyUpdates
```

But when used within Invoke-Command the script get stuck forever...

So in order to troubleshoot my script I would like to see the live output of the command above...

When you run dcu-cli.exe in a cmd, you see the progress in the cmd GUI, is there any possibilities to redirect the live out-put to my Powershell prompt ?

I would also have some question regarding dcu-cli syntax as here are my thoughts for complete update :

```
Invoke-command -computername $Computer -credential $CredObject -Scriptblock {
cmd /c start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe" -argumentlist 
/configure -biosPassword="$usingBIOSPWD" ;
cmd /c start /wait "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe" -argumentlist /ApplyUpdates }
```

Above, script get stuck with no errors...I'd like it to first save the bios-password from my script variables and then run all the updates.

Problem is dcu-cli.exe doesn't accept his own switches sometimes (while I'm trying all kind of possibilities...Start-process ; cmd ; &.....)
Is it possible when running cmd through powershell to see the cmd live output ?

If I run dcu-cli with cmd it run fine but I'm not sure how to pass the object and the variable into a batch or any other way that would allow me to see the installation progress...

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm working on this for weeks and I'm a newbie in Powershell :)

PS : Yes I did use google about it already

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still trying to figure it out...but I've managed to invoke DCU on remote machine using Task Scheduler.
Those simple few lines in `PowerShell` create task on machine with trigger at current time + 1 minute with SYSTEM privilages:

```
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $(Get-Date).AddMinutes(1)
$User = "SYSTEM"
$Actions = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "powershell.exe" -Argument "Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe' -ArgumentList '/scan -report=`"C:\Temp\`"'"
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit "01:00" -AllowStartIfOnBatteries
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Actions -Trigger $Trigger -Settings $Settings -Description 'Update process'
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "DCU Updates Scan" -InputObject $Task -User $User -Force
```

`-report="C:\Temp\"'` redirects out-put to specified location.

Just modify agument list in `New-ScheduledTaskAction` and you should be ready to go.

Cheers